# Reading bank account numbers and balances from file, sorting in asccending order, using binary search to find balances accompanied by account number

Tags: c++

After writing this program and not having to much code written with functions I was looking for some advice. So how'd I do readability wise? Are the functions organized? Should they be organized differently? etc.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    void readData(int[], double[], ifstream & inputFile);
    double assortData(int[], double[]);
    void newFile(int[], double[], ofstream & outputFile);
    int binarySearch(const int[], int, int);
    void getAccNum(int &);

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;                // Global Array Size

    int main()
    {
        int results;                            // BinarySearch result
        int accNUM;                             // Account number entered by user
        int accountNumbers[ARRAY_SIZE];         // Array with 1000 elements. Stores bank account numbers
        double accountBalances[ARRAY_SIZE];     // Array with 1000 elements. Stores bank account balances

        ifstream inputFile;                     // Input file stream object
        ofstream outputFile;                    // Output file stream object

        // Open the file storing bank account numbers and corresponding account balances. Read the data
        inputFile.open("FinalNumbers.txt");
        readData(accountNumbers, accountBalances, inputFile);

        // Close the file when done with it.
        inputFile.close();

        // Assorts account numbers from file into ascending order
        assortData(accountNumbers, accountBalances);

        // Opens another file and puts sorted data into the file
        outputFile.open("Final_Random_Accounts_Sorted_Mazzei_Chris.txt");
        newFile(accountNumbers, accountBalances, outputFile);

        // Close the file when done with it.
        outputFile.close();

        // Gets account number from user input.
        getAccNum(accNUM);
        // Gets account balance corresponding to users bank account number
        results = binarySearch(accountNumbers, ARRAY_SIZE, accNUM);

        // Check for valid bank account number. Output accordingly
        if (results == -1) {
            cout << "ERROR invalid account number\nProgram ending" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "The balance for account number " << accNUM << " is: " << accountBalances[results] << endl;
        }

    }

    void readData(int numbers[], double balances[], ifstream & input)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && input >> numbers[count] >> balances[count] ) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    double assortData(int numbers[], double balances[])
    {
        int tempAccNumber = 0;
        int tempAccBalance = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1 ; ++j)
            for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; ++i)
                if (numbers[i] > numbers [i + 1])
                {
                    tempAccNumber = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i +1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = tempAccNumber;
                    tempAccBalance = balances[i];
                    balances[i] = balances[i + 1];
                    balances[i + 1] = tempAccBalance;
                }

        return 0;
    }

    void newFile(int numbers[], double balances[], ofstream & output)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            output << numbers[i] << endl;
            output << balances[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    void getAccNum(int &usersAccNum)
    {
        cout << "Enter an account number to be found: ";
        cin >> usersAccNum;
    }

    int binarySearch(const int array[], int size, int value)

    {
        int first = 0,
        last = size - 1,
        middle,
        position = - 1;
        bool found = false;

        while (!found && first <= last) {
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
            if (array[middle] == value) {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
            }
            else if (array[middle] > value)
                last = middle - 1;
            else
                first = middle + 1;

        }

        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a straightforward way to implement this. I'm able to read it and understand what it does. I appreciate that you made `ARRAY_SIZE` a constant and not a `#define`! You've nicely broken things like reading the data from the files into separate functions, which is great. I think you could make it better by doing some of the following things.

## Objects

C++ is an object-oriented language. The beauty of object oriented programming is that it allows you to come up with sensible abstractions for the things (objects) that you want to represent and the messages (methods) they pass to each other to accomplish a task. You can see this with the `ifstream` and `ofstream` classes that have methods for opening and reading data from files. You should do something similar.

For example, you have parallel arrays for the account numbers and the account balances. But wouldn't it make more sense to have an account class that holds the account number and the balance? Then you could have a single array of accounts. It would make your `assortData()` function much simpler because you wouldn't be trying to keep 2 different arrays in synch with one another.

Additionally, C++ comes with a wide variety of very useful classes. You're already using some of them from the standard template library. I recommend you look into `std::vector`. They are similar to C arrays, but can be sized dynamically. There are also functions for sorting them so you don't have to write your own. (Though it's always good to write these things at least once to make sure you have a solid understanding of how they work.)

## Avoid `using namespace std`

There are many people who can explain this far better than I can. [Here's a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice#1452738).

## Error Handling

Your `binarySearch` function returns an error if it doesn't find the account. That's great! Now what about the other functions? What if `readData()` runs into an error with the input file? (Like maybe there aren't enough entries in the file, or there are too many?) What if the user enters an invalid account number (like one that has letters or symbols in it)?

## Don't Put Too Many Things In a Conditional

In your `readData()` function the condition on your `while` statement is fairly confusing. It is checking that the count is within range, and it's reading the `input` into the numbers array, and into the `balances` array. I would make this clearer by checking that we haven't reached the end of the array, and that the input is valid by doing something like this:

```
bool inputValid = true;
while ((count < ARRAY_SIZE) && (inputValid))
{
    inputValid = (input >> numbers [ count ]);
    inputValid &= (input >> balances [ count ]);
    inputValid &= (balances [ count ] != 0);
    if (inputValid)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

<s>Also, in your version, if a balance or account number is 0, will that end the loop? (I haven't tried it, but it seems like it could.)</s> I mistakenly thought that the `operator>>()` would return the value in question, but in fact it returns a reference to the stream you're reading from. As such, if you want to check the validity, you need to explicitly check that the balance you read in was not 0.

**Update:** So, as you can see, it's hard to get these things right. As Loki Astari pointed out, I messed it up not once, but twice (so far!). My main point, though, is that while putting a stream read into the condition of the `while` loop may work, it's going to get cumbersome quickly as your data model grows. Right now it's only 2 pieces of data, but in the future, you might have names and addresses or phone numbers, or linked accounts, etc. Also, if you want to report back specific errors, it can get hard if all you know is that 1 of 2 or 5 or 10 pieces of data was bad. Which one? Is it recoverable?

## Use Braces Even For 1-Line Expressions

In `assortData()` you don't have curly braces around either `for` loop. While this is legal, it can lead to bugs when some future programmer (including you) decides to add 1 more statement to one of the loops. If they don't realize there are no braces, they will likely forget to add them, thus changing the meaning of the loop. Everything after the new statement will not be part of the loop. Or if they try to put it at the end, it will execute only once, and not on every iteration.

Comment: Wow wasn't expecting all this so let me start by saying thank you. Definitely going to start implementing your suggestions, not because you said to but because it all makes sense. (I hope that came out right). The only thing I must bring up is "Also, in your version, if a balance or account number is 0, will that end the loop? (I haven't tried it, but it seems like it could.)". Yes it will end the loop and I want it to in this case, the data is all pre written with lowest balance being well above 0 and account numbers ranging from 10,000 - 10999. - sorry +1 doesn't show up yet with reputation.

Comment: The "will that that end the loop" is wrong. The loop will only end when there is no more numbers available. The number 0 is not a special case.

Comment: Ah, right. I was thinking that the `operator>>()` would return the value it read, which would be `0`, which would be equivalent to `false` which would cause the loop to end. But in fact, `operator>>()` returns a reference to a stream. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: **BUG**. Your read is still wrong. The last successful read with `operator>>` will read up-to but not past the end of file. Thus your file will be empty but the `eof` flag is not set and the stream will be in a good state. So the while loop will be entered and the two subsequent reads will fail `balance[count]` will be left unchanged (thus probably indeterminate) and your code to increment `count` will still be executed. It is standard to test the read operations by putting them in the while condition. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/14065

Comment: -1 until you fix that bug in your while.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen it done that way. However, I don't do a lot of stream processing in my work, so I'm not surprised by that. I've updated it to work as I think it's supposed to, but still not inline. Let me know if it looks good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1118321: Your code is still wrong. As you increment `count` even if the read fails. Thus you have an off by one error.

Comment: Not sure why a balance of zero marks the end that's not in the spec I read above. Magic numbers are very brittle avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 3):

Just have to say that @user1118321 advice about the loop is **wrong**. In fact what he has suggested is an anti pattern (a very common mistake).

Now I agree that it would be nice to make that conditional shorter. But that is achieved by using his first bit of advice and creating a class (object) for back accounts.

But the pattern as advocated:

```
while(stream)
{
    stream >> value[count];
    ++count;
}
```

Is **WRONG**. The problem is that the read can fail (even if at the beginning of the loop it is in a good state). This is true for all languages this is not unique to C or C++.

So you must test that the read worked. The first update to this is:

```
while(stream)
{
    if (stream >> value[count]) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

So the first update to the above pattern is to check that the read worked and only perform your other actions if the read worked. This is a perfectly acceptable way to do it.

**But** it is still not the best way. The **standard** way of reading from a stream is to put the read test in the while condition.

```
while(stream >> value[count])
{
    ++count;
}
```

Now the loop is only entered if the read operation succeeds.

Comment: Keep in mind there are 2 values that need to be read from the stream, and either could fail.

Comment: @user1118321 I was explaining the pattern not the specific instance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to review the overall design here - which may have been imposed on you, but I'll assume you get to choose.

#### Start with the data structures!

What you are manipulating is a set of bank balances, identified by account number.  The number is inseparable from the balance, so we want to encapsulate them into a single object:

```
struct Account
{
    unsigned int ref_number;
    long balance;
}
```

I've assumed that account numbers are always positive; I've also used an integer type for the value (in the smallest units of the currency) - see [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3730019) for a fuller explanation.

Next, how are we going to use these account objects?  We want to keep them in sorted order; we can use C++'s standard containers to help here: instead of reading into a fixed-size array, and then sorting the array, we can use a container that resizes itself and keeps itself in sorted order.  The natural choices for this are `std::set` and `std::map`.  The map has an advantage for us, because it will pair the account number with the balance amount for us, so we don't need to create the `Account` object I showed above.

```
#include <map>

std::map<unsigned int, long> accountBalances = readAccounts(filename);
```

We now need a definition of `readAccounts()`:

```
constexpr long toCents(double d)
{
    // 100 cents in a Euro; round to nearest
    return static_cast<long>(d * 100 + .5);
}

std::map<unsigned int, long> readAccounts(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::map<unsigned int, long> accounts;

    std::ifstream is{filename};
    unsigned int n;
    double d;
    while (is >> n >> d) {
        if (!accounts.emplace(n, toCents(d)).second)
            std::cerr << "Warning: ignoring duplicate account number " << n << std::endl;
    }

    return accounts;
}
```

Saving the accounts is a simple loop (it's already in sorted order):

```
void writeAccounts(const std::map<unsigned int, long>& accounts, const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ofstream os{filename};
    for (const auto& account: accounts)
        if (!(os << account.first << " " << account.second << "\n"))
            break;
    if (!os)
        std::cerr << "Warning: failed to write accounts to " << filename << std::endl;
}
```

Looking up the balance of a single account is even simpler, as it's a simple call to `std::map::at()`.